# Redirection of xml file for iphone app

Tags: php, iphone, redirect, server-side, xml

I have a xml file on my server like the one below :

```
www.myWebSite.com/myXmlFile.xml
```

which is used by my iphone application.

In case the address of my xml file changes to

```
www.myOtherWebsite.com/myXmlFile.xml
```

How can I make my app to work anyway ? What kind of PHP server-side code do I need to write ? Is NSURLConnection supporting reirections ?

Thanks for any incomings ;)

Gotye.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be use [PHP-CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to write a PHP script that will reside in:

www.myWebSite.com/myXmlFile.xml

And will open a HTTP connection (with CURL) to:

www.myOtherWebsite.com/myXmlFile.xml

It's pretty straightforward and there are a lot of examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NSURLConnection will support redirects at the HTTP level. It will do redirects by default; you can also control whether or not to allow the redirect from the NSURLConnection delegate.

See [URL Loading System: Handling Redirects and Other Request Changes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html)

On the server side, you can send a redirect from PHP like:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.myOtherWebsite.com/myXmlFile.xml");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: And as long as my file is still on www.myWebSite.com, can I do 

<?php
header("Location: http://www.myWebsite.com/myXmlFile.xml");
exit;
?>

or is it a bad move to do a redirection if I can avoid it ?